# findall Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated

Tags: prolog, instantiation-error

I have simplified  my code down to;

```
findall(T,(T > 0, T < 50),List).
```

Why would this fail with given error.

Comment: Because `T` never gets a value. There are easier ways to get a list of ints.

Answer (score 3):

Here is your code simplified even further:

```
?- T > 0.
ERROR: >/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

The "classical" comparison operations like `<` and `>` need all their arguments to be fully instantiated to ground terms; in particular, they cannot be unbound variables. (The same is true for the term on the right-hand-side of the `is/2` operator.)

You can *not* use these operators as generators. Here is one illustration of a possible reason why:

```
?- T = 1, T > 0.
T = 1.

?- T = 0.1, T > 0.
T = 0.1.

?- T = 0.01, T > 0.
T = 0.01.

?- T = 0.001, T > 0.
T = 0.001.
```

The `>` operator works for several different types of numbers, including floating-point numbers. If we wanted it to be a logically reasonable generator, it would have to be able to *generate* all the floating-point numbers it accepts in the example above. That would almost certainly not be what you want.

There are a few ways to get what you want. As you presumably want integers only, you can use the `between/3` predicate provided by many Prolog systems (including SWI):

```
?- between(1, 49, T).
T = 1 ;
T = 2 ;
T = 3 ;
T = 4 .

?- findall(T, between(1, 49, T), List).
List = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9|...].
```

Another possibility is to use a constraint programming library. Here is one example session with SWI-Prolog's `clpfd` library:

```
?- use_module(library(clpfd)).
true.

?- T #> 0, T #< 50.
T in 1..49.
```

Note that here, using `#>` and `#<` from the `clpfd` library instead of `<` and `>`, we *can* actually specify these constraints even on an unbound variable. These constraints are remembered for later use, but they do *not* enumerate actual values for `T`. You can use them in arithmetic and comparisons, and the system will sometimes reason things out correctly even though it doesn't enumerate concrete values! For example:

```
?- T #> 0, T #< 50, X #= T - 50, X #> 50.
false.
```

To get actual values, you call a specific predicate that enumerates them:

```
?- T #> 0, T #< 50, indomain(T).
T = 1 ;
T = 2 ;
T = 3 ;
T = 4 .
```

All this gives another possible solution for your problem:

```
?- findall(T, (T #> 0, T #< 50, indomain(T)), List).
List = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9|...].
```

Comment: Can also use [numlist](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=numlist/3): `numlist(1,49,List)`

Comment: Or `T in 1..49.`

Comment: Isnt prolog supposed to supply the value and run the statement according to it?

Comment: As I wrote (did you read my answer?), Prolog cannot do this in the case of arithmetic, for various reasons. If you want to compare numbers, usually you have to know what those numbers are. Otherwise, learn about constraint programming with `clpfd`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want filtering, how about writing like this:

```
bagof(T,(member(T,[0,-4,34,15,76,100,200,43,21]),T>0,T<50),List).
```

List will be [34,15,43,21].
(though I didn't test)

If you just want to enumurate 1 to 49, ignore this answer(others have already answered)